# On the history of field theories on curved spacetime

Tags: history, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I would like to know what were the first actors studying the subject and the first articles written about it; also the first problems and results. If it's possible also the main steps in the evolution. If you know something about the authors, their motivation to study the subject at the time, the results that they expected, if they did, I like it too. I know it is a very broad question; I'm approaching the subject for a thesis work and I don't know anything, but I'm very curios about it, so any insight on its history is of extreme value for me, thanks.

Comment: Since this isn't a resource recommendation question, I will post this as a comment, but you might be interested on the recollections made by [Fulling](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1984qtg..book...42F/abstract), [Wald](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0608018), and [Parker](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07132). All three of them lived and played major roles in the history of QFTCS

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because I believe this question might be better suited for [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you @NíckolasAlves for the suggestions. I didn't even know there was this kind of section, I will ask the question there